# YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (3.6.0+) support

Tags: python-3.x, vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

i have vim 8.2.850. I am trying to install YouCompleteMe. But get this error, when trying to open vim:

`"YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (3.6.0+) support"`

How can i fix this? i saw other ppl answer for different versions. But sorry im a noob, could someone please help and give a detailed explaination on how to fix it?

And i am on mac, using terminal

Comment: https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

Comment: Recommend you try coc.nvim or nvim.lsp; source: https://www.reddit.com/r/vimporn/comments/lgksrq/comment/goeshsx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 14):

It is an old question but I wanted to add I simply installed *macvim* and re-started terminal again. It solved my problem

```
- brew install macvim
```

Comment: I use terminal vim, but installing this somehow fixed my terminal vim as well ! Thanks :)

Comment: Same here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I'm aware that this isn't directed at your question per say, but I ran into the same issue on Ubuntu with nvim.
Reinstalling didn't help, but adding https://github.com/neovim/pynvim fixed my issue.
Perhaps it can be helpful to Mac users using nvim too.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `vim --version | grep python` to check your vim. If vim detects the python3, it will show like:

```bash
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +virtualedit
```

The `python3` will have a `+` sign in front of that.

If not, first, you must check if you have `python3`.

Second, you need to uninstall vim (`sudo apt purge vim`), then reinstall vim (`sudo apt install vim`).

Third. Reconfirmation by `vim --version | grep python`.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I have `python3` install and proceeded with the uninstall and reinstall as you suggest but I still have a `-` instead of `+` in front of `python3`

Comment: In the end, following these steps as well as installing `python3-dev` was able to get the `+python` in my versioning. In my opinion this is the cleanest solution that required the fewest modifications or installs that didn't make sense +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reinstall the latest vim version with homebrew: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/vim

But, I think you should recheck your vim version with `:version`, there is no version like yours.

And the latest version itself depends on python, and more like nvim.

```
# I do like this
brew install vim --HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed

```
brew install macvim
```

worked for me after restarting terminal.
Make sure to

```
brew uninstall vim
```

before installing macvim, then restart terminal.
Solved it for me on new Mac with new apple chip.

Answer (score -1):

Thankfully, the error message is pretty solid. You need vim with Python,
Now while I don't personally have a mac that should be as straightforward as making sure you install the correct version.

The simplest way is probably going to be with brew as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1115159/how-do-i-install-vim-on-osx-with-python-3-support).

```
brew remove vim
brew cleanup
brew install vim --with-python
```

If you installed it with a binary you will need to find a new binary with python included. Or alternatively you could try and build it from source as the comment from Zoe suggested. But I think that may be somewhat more involved than ideal for a beginner, although worthwhile.

---

It doesn't seem, like this actually involves neovim at all, If it does then you may want to update your question, otherwise it is a good idea to remove the neovim tag.